# Complex regex statements

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to study up on regex; however, I cannot seem to grasp what these two regex statements are saying.

```
private static final Pattern BALANCED_TEXT =
    Pattern.compile("(?s)((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\{}]"
                    + "|[{](?:\\\\.|[^\\\\{}])*[}])*)"
                    + "\\}"
                    + "|.");

private static final Pattern INPUT_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("(?s)(\\p{Blank}+)"
                    + "|(\\r?\\n((?:\\r?\\n)+)?)"
                    + "|\\\\([\\p{Blank}{}\\\\])"
                    + "|\\\\(\\p{Alpha}+)([{]?)"
                    + "|((?:[^\\p{Blank}\\r\\n\\\\{}]+))"
                    + "|(.)");
```

I would appreciate it if someone could explain these two regex statements to me in depth. Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `(?s)` is DOTALL flag. It will let dot `.` also match new line marks. `\\p{Blank}` is the same as space or tabulator `[ \t]` so you can replace it in your regex. Also `\\p{Alpha}` is the same as `[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]` which is the same as `[a-zA-Z]`. Now just print `BALANCED_TEXT` and `INPUT_PATTERN` and use them on https://www.debuggex.com/ and http://regex101.com/ to see how they work. Also remove `(?s)` if needed.

Comment: I am confused on what ?: and [^\\\\{}] mean. Also what is the point of the + sign?

Comment: You said that you have bean trying to study regex :/ `+` means that element or group before it can repeat one or more times. `(?:xxx)` is [non capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/1393766). `[^abc]` means every character except these inside `[^...]` so in case of `[^\\\\{}]` it is the same as every character but not \, {, or }.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole first regex is:

`(?s)((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\{}]|[{](?:\\\\.|[^\\\\{}])*[}])*)\\}|.`

First you should do away with java string escapes (e.g. `\\` to mean `\`). You get a regex:

`(?s)((?:\\.|[^\\{}]|[{](?:\\.|[^\\{}])*[}])*)\}|.`

First thing is `(?s)` a DOTALL flag with makes `.` match newlines.
Second thing to look at is top level structure. Since `|` is an OR operator, with lowest precedence, it's:

`(something)\} OR SINGLE ANY CHARACTER - DOT`

So it will first try to match something ending with `}` (since `}` is a special character in regex it's prefaced with `\`. The part before `}` will be matched as group 1 because of the `()` around it.

Let's look at what's inside the outermost `()`.

The outermost form is `(?: something)*`. It will match 0 or more repetitions of `something`.

The `(?: )` means that what's inside is a non-capturing group, that is, it doesn't generate a group in match like `( )` would. It allows the `|` OR expressions to correctly alternate with each other without including the outtermost `|.`.

Let's look what that `something` is. It's a series of OR expressions, which are tried from left to right.

First one is `\\.` which matches `\` followed by any character (notice `\\` is escaped `\`, while `.` is not escaped.

The second one is a character class `[\\{}]` which matches any character that is not `\` or `{` or `}`.

Third one is matches character `{` followed by 0 or more matches of the inner `(?: )` followed by `}`. Inner `(?: )` matches either `\` followed by any character or any character which is not `\` or `{` or `}`.

So if you put this together this matches:

First part will match anything that ends with `}` (group 1 will not include `}` while whole match can. Before last `}` it will match:

- Empty string
- Any characters escaped by `\`
- Sequences of characters between `{` `}`

better explained as: it will match pretty much anything except `\` by itself, `{` `}` without each other, it won't match nested `{` `}` pairs. Above exceptions can be escaped by `\`.

It will also match any character at all (the last `.`) but that match will have empty group 1.

Samples of (java unescaped) strings that match:

`a}`, `h{ello}}`, `h{\{ello}}`, `x`, `h{\\ello}}`, `{}}`

Seems like that regex is wrong since it won't match `{}` but it will match `}` and `{}}` while being named `BALANCED_TEXT`.